# Why use libcurl?

Tags: sockets, libcurl

I'm just learning the basics of socket programming for C++, but I've heard people mentioning libcurl fairly often. What's the advantage of using libcurl instead of programming sockets the traditional way?

Also, what are the differences between libcurl, curl, and curl++? Which one should I be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libcurl` is a library for communicating with different web services like FTP or HTTP and is no replacement for `socket`.

To learn the basics of socket programming, you have to use `socket`.

The differences:

- `curl` is the binary
- `libcurl` is the c-library
- `curl++` a c++-library

Comment: curl++ is actually "just" a C++ binding on top of the regular libcurl library

Answer (score 3):

`libcurl` handles *application level* protocols, so you don't have to write your own HTTP client code (for example).

Keep learning the basics - it'll give you a better base from which to understand how libraries like `libcurl` are implemented.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that using libcurl with http webserver will be simpler than writing socket application which http communicate with a web server ?